# Some C Floating Point Constants Don't Make Sense

Tags: c, floating-point, constants, ieee-754

The constants in `<float.h>` for `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)` don't seem to make sense.

`DBL_MIN_EXP` is `-1021` and `DBL_MAX_EXP` is `1024`. However, that doesn't match what [wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64), "exponents range from −1022 to +1023, ..."

Also `DBL_MIN_EXP` seems inconsistent with `DBL_MIN` which is `2.2250738585072014e-308` which is equal to `2⁻¹⁰²²` sometimes written as `0x1.0000000000000p-1022`.  So, we have an exponent smaller than the minimum `-1021`.

Likewise, `DBL_MIN_10_EXP` is `-307` which doesn't sense given that `DBL_MIN` has an exponent of `e-308`.

The double `DBL_MAX_EXP` value of `1024` overflows when used in real code.  For example, `ldexp(1.0, 1024)` gives `inf`.

Here's my C code:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define SHOW_DOUBLE(s)   printf("%.17lg \t%s\n", s, #s);
#define SHOW_INT(s)      printf("%d \t%s\n", s, #s);

int
main()
{
    SHOW_DOUBLE(DBL_MAX);
    SHOW_DOUBLE(DBL_MIN);
    SHOW_DOUBLE(DBL_EPSILON);
    SHOW_INT(DBL_MAX_EXP);
    SHOW_INT(DBL_MAX_10_EXP);
    SHOW_INT(DBL_MIN_EXP);
    SHOW_INT(DBL_MIN_10_EXP);
    SHOW_INT(DBL_DIG);
    SHOW_INT(DBL_MANT_DIG);
    SHOW_INT(FLT_RADIX);
    SHOW_INT(FLT_ROUNDS);
    printf("%lf\n", ldexp(1.0, 1024));
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
1.7976931348623157e+308 DBL_MAX
2.2250738585072014e-308 DBL_MIN
2.2204460492503131e-16  DBL_EPSILON
1024                    DBL_MAX_EXP
308                     DBL_MAX_10_EXP
-1021                   DBL_MIN_EXP
-307                    DBL_MIN_10_EXP
15                      DBL_DIG
53                      DBL_MANT_DIG
2                       FLT_RADIX
1                       FLT_ROUNDS
inf
```

Comment: have you compared with float.h file from other systems? I have the exact same result for gcc on Windows

Comment: Same picture: https://ideone.com/mK3e05

Comment: Well, from the C standard: *minimum negative integer such that FLT_RADIX raised to **one less** than that power is a normalized floating-point number, emin*

Comment: for max: /* Maximum int x such that FLT_RADIX**(x-1) is a representable float, emax.  */

Answer (score 9):

The off-by-one is part of the spec. From *5.2.4.2.2 Characteristics of floating types <float.h>, ¶11*,

> ...
>
> - minimum negative integer such that FLT_RADIX raised to **one less than** that power is a normalized floating-point number, emin
>
>   - FLT_MIN_EXP
>   - DBL_MIN_EXP
>   - LDBL_MIN_EXP
>
> ...
>
> - maximum integer such that FLT_RADIX raised to **one less than** that power is a representable finite floating-point number, emax
>
>   - FLT_MAX_EXP
>   - DBL_MAX_EXP
>   - LDBL_MAX_EXP

Emphasis on **one less than** is mine.

Comment: And the "one less than" makes sense when you understand that these two are expressing properties associated with C's model for representing floating-point numbers (which appears at the beginning of the referenced section of the standard), not directly the properties of extreme numbers themselves.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Could you clarify how that makes sense?

Comment: The floating-point model represents numbers as (*sign*) * (`FLT_RADIX` ^ *exponent*) * (*fraction*), where *fraction* is between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive) and *sign* is either 1 or -1.  The \*_MAX_EXP and \*_MIN_EXP are type-specific maximum and minimum values for the *exponent* parameter in that formula, and as such, they are pretty natural.  The definitions you quoted from the standard express them in terms of the resulting floating-point values instead of the in terms of the model, which is that description might seem surprising.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: Ah, so because the "fraction" is in [0,1) (really [0.5,1) if you're assuming normalization) rather than [1,2) as in normal conventions.

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question and realized that this stems from the fact that IEEE 754 and C use two different [normalized forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significand#Example):

- IEEE 754 uses a *significand* between 1 (inclusive) and 2 (exclusive) for **normal numbers**:

> *x* = *sign* × *significand* × 2<sup>*exponent*</sup>, encoded as *S*|*E*|*F* where *sign* = (−1)<sup>*S*</sup>; *significand* =
>
> - **1.*F* if *E*<sub>min</sub> ≤ *E* ≤ *E*<sub>max</sub> (normal number),**
> - 0 if *E* = *E*<sub>min</sub> − 1 and *F* = 0 (zero),
> - 0.*F* if *E* = *E*<sub>min</sub> − 1 and *F* ≠ 0 (subnormal number),
> - ∞ if *E* = *E*<sub>max</sub> + 1 and *F* = 0 (infinity),
> - NaN if *E* = *E*<sub>max</sub> + 1 and *F* ≠ 0 (not a number);
>
> *exponent* = max(*E*, *E*<sub>min</sub>) − *exponent bias*.

- C uses a *significand′* between 0.5 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive) for **normal numbers**:

> *x* = *sign′* × *significand′* × 2<sup>*exponent′*</sup>, encoded as *S*|*E*|*F* where *sign′* = (−1)<sup>*S*</sup>; *significand′* =
>
> - **0.1*F* if *E*<sub>min</sub> ≤ *E* ≤ *E*<sub>max</sub> (normal number),**
> - 0 if *E* = *E*<sub>min</sub> − 1 and *F* = 0 (zero),
> - 0.0*F* if *E* = *E*<sub>min</sub> − 1 and *F* ≠ 0 (subnormal number),
> - ∞ if *E* = *E*<sub>max</sub> + 1 and *F* = 0 (infinity),
> - NaN if *E* = *E*<sub>max</sub> + 1 and *F* ≠ 0 (not a number);
>
> *exponent′* = max(*E* + 1, *E*<sub>min</sub> + 1) − *exponent bias*.

Since *x* = *sign* × *significand* × 2<sup>*exponent*</sup> = *sign′* × *significand′* × 2<sup>*exponent′*</sup>, the following relations between the IEEE 754 normalized form and the C normalized form hold:

- *sign′* = *sign*;
- *significand′* = *significand*/2;
- *exponent′* = *exponent* + 1.

In particular, in binary64 format that is why *exponent*<sub>min</sub> = −1022 in IEEE 754 normalized form and *exponent′*<sub>min</sub> = −1021 in C normalized form (`DBL_MIN_EXP`), and *exponent*<sub>max</sub> = 1023 in IEEE 754 normalized form and *exponent′*<sub>max</sub> = 1024 in C normalized form (`DBL_MAX_EXP`).

In Python:

- the IEEE 754 normalized *significand* and *exponent* can be extracted with:

```py
math.ldexp(x, -math.floor(math.log2(x))), math.floor(math.log2(x))
```

- the C normalized *significand′* and *exponent′* can be extracted with:

```py
math.frexp(x)
```

For instance:

```py
>>> import math
>>> x = 12
>>> math.ldexp(x, -math.floor(math.log2(x))), math.floor(math.log2(x))
(1.5, 3)
>>> math.frexp(12)
(0.75, 4)
```